# Insert update data help in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a insert update procedure where I am getting data from 2 procedures and putting the data in to a table.

So procedure 1 has data like this

```
AgentName   Tickets Closed
----------------------------
Agent1        10
Agent2         2
Agent3         4
Agent4         6
Agent5         9
Agent6        12
```

Procedure 2 has data like this

```
AgentName   Active Tickets
--------------------------
Agent1           2
Agent9           3
Agent10          1
Agent2           0
Agent3           0
Agent11          1
```

So now in my insert update procedure I am getting only matching data into destination table from both the procedures.

But I need to get unmatched data also.

Below is my code for Procedure 1:

```
BEGIN
insert into Table1
( 
Date1,
Agent,
TicketsCompleted
)
exec Procedure1 


declare @TicketsCompleted table
(
Date1 datetime,
TicketsCompleted int
)
insert into @TicketsCompleted
exec Procedure1 

update Table1
set TicketsCompleted= ptc.TicketsCompleted
from Table1 eps , @TicketsCompleted ptc
where eps.date1=ptc.Date1
and eps.Agent=ptc.Agent
```

Here is my Procedure 2:

```
declare @TicketsActive table
(
Date1 datetime,
TicketsActive int
)
insert into @TicketsActive
exec Procedure2

update Table1
set TicketsActive= ptc.TicketsActive
from Table1 eps , @TicketsActive ptc
where eps.date1=ptc.Date1
and eps.Agent=ptc.Agent
```

Comment: Look into using `MERGE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get data from tables Table1, @TicketsComplited, @TicketsActiv with no match

```
SELECT * FROM
Table1 eps FULL JOIN 
@TicketsCompleted ptc
On eps.date1=ptc.Date1
and eps.Agent=ptc.Agent
Where eps.date1 is null 
or ptc.Date1 is null 
Or eps.Agent is null 
or ptc.Agent is null



    SELECT * FROM
    Table1 eps FULL JOIN 
    @TicketsActive ptc
    On eps.date1=ptc.Date1
    and eps.Agent=ptc.Agent
    Where eps.date1 is null 
    or ptc.Date1 is null 
    Or eps.Agent is null 
    or ptc.Agent is null
```

Comment: And for other tables

Answer (score 0):

Well if I'm getting you correctly, I can suggest you to use one of the two below approaches.

- SQL [NOT and IN](http://from%20Table1%20eps%20,%20@TicketsCompleted%20ptc%20where%20eps.date1=ptc.Date1%20and%20eps.Agent=ptc.Agent) clauses:

```sql
...
SELECT COLUMNS_YOU_WANT FROM 
(
   QUERY_FOR_SOME_FILTERING
   WHERE YOUR_UNIQUE_COL NOT IN 
   (
      QUERY_FOR_SOME_FILTERING
   )
)
```

- SQL [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause:

```sql
SELECT COL1, COL2, etc. 
FROM 
    QUERY_FOR_SOME_FILTERING
EXCEPT 
(
    SELECT COL1, COL2, etc. FROM 
    QUERY_FOR_SOME_FILTERING
)
```

Comment: Hi @Arsen Could you please explain clearly ? What do you mean by COL1, COL2, etc and QUERY_FOR_SOME_FILTERING

Comment: @Raja `COL1`,`COL2` are the columns you want to select, and `QUERY_FOR_SOME_FILTERING` is you query that you use for the filtering results `from Table1 eps , @TicketsCompleted ptc  where eps.date1=ptc.Date1 and 
 ps.Agent=ptc.Agent`. For more details please also check the documentation I've linked to the answer.