# Matching and unlatching records in a single table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, full-outer-join

I have procedure where I am getting data from my 1st temp table like below

[image]

2nd temp table like below

[image]

Now I need to join this 2 temp tables to get all matching and unmatching data .My result would be like below

[image]

[image]

But I am getting only matching data.Please help how to do

Comment: This is a duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197725/insert-update-data-help-in-sql-server/63198980#63198980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a `full join`:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.agentName, t2.agentName) agentName,
    coalesce(t1.completedTickets, 0) completedTickets,
    coalesce(t2.activeTickets, 0) activeTickets
from t1
full join t2 on t2.agentName = t1.agentName
```

Comment: Hi @GMB you approach is working.But I have 12 temp tables in my procedure.For coalesce I need to keep 12 times agent names and also need to do 12 joins.Would that be okay ?Please suggest